# Apache Spark: Type conversion problem on write using JDBC driver to SQL Server / Azure DWH for column of BINARY type

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My initial goal is to save UUId values to SQL Server/Azure DWH to column of BINARY(16) type.

For example, I have demo table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Events] ([EventId] [binary](16) NOT NULL)
```

I want to write data to it using Spark like this:

```scala
import java.util.UUID

val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
val uuidBytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](16)
ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes)
        .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
        .putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
        .putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("EventId", BinaryType, false)
  )
)
val data = Seq((uuidBytes)).toDF("EventId").rdd;
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

df.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "<DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL>")
  .option("dbTable", "Events")
  .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

This code returns an error:
`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Conversion from variable or parameter type VARBINARY to target column type BINARY is not supported.`

My question is how to cope with this situation and insert UUId value to BINARY(16) column?

My investigation:

Spark uses conception of JdbcDialects and has a mapping for each Catalyst type to database type and vice versa. For example here is [MsSqlServerDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/MsSqlServerDialect.scala) which is used when we work against SQL Server or Azure DWH. In the method `getJDBCType` you can see the mapping:

```scala
case BinaryType => Some(JdbcType("VARBINARY(MAX)", java.sql.Types.VARBINARY))
```

and this is the root of my problem as I think.

So, I decide to implement my own JdbcDialect to override this behavior:

```scala
class SqlServerDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String) : Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:sqlserver")

  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
    case BinaryType => Option(JdbcType("BINARY(16)", java.sql.Types.BINARY))
    case _ => None
  }
}

val dialect = new SqlServerDialect
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(dialect)
```

With this modification I still catch exactly the same error. It looks like that Spark do not use mapping from my custom dialect. But I checked that the dialect is registered. So it is strange situation.

Comment: were able to resolve it?

Comment: It looks like the problem on the SqlServer side. I can't find the solution. The workaround here is to use VARBINARY(16) datatype when creating a table in the SqlServer.